# How to get the insights data in instagram

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-insights

Does [instagram.com/developer](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) provide any way to get the insights data of a user ? (NOT the business Account)

Also, what is Instagram Product ?

Comment: Instagram official developer portal does not provides any insight for individual account or business account. You can fetch insight metrics for your business account insight using Facebook graph api explorer